# Tweepy api.search Tweet timestamp?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy to make a little script that fetches Tweets that match a query and writes them to a csv. It checks as often as it can, and just pulls the most recent 15 tweets. I'm using [Tweepy's api.search](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/api.html#API.search).  No problems in the actual script. I just can't find the timestamp field from Tweepy's output. These are the fields I found:

```
['created_at', 'from_user', 'from_user_id', 'from_user_id_str', 'from_user_name', 'geo', 'id', 'id_str', 'in_reply_to_status_id', 'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'iso_language_code', 'metadata', 'profile_image_url', 'profile_image_url_https', 'source', 'text', 'to_user', 'to_user_id', 'to_user_id_str', 'to_user_name']
```

Unfortunately I need a timestamp. Does anyone know if this is supported? If not, anyone got a better python module? If there was something that was streaming that I could leverage, that might be a better solution anyway...

So grateful for the help.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445875/getting-a-steady-flow-of-messages-from-twitter

Comment: don't think tweepy support is available for over 2.5 but the other question may help you

Comment: Sorry, that's not correct. And, the question is about Tweepy itself, not my python script.

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp is the `created_at` field.

Comment: @alecxe... How about time zone.